# Android: Landscape support for drawables on large-mdpi/hdpi screens?

Tags: android

I have an app, it runs on both handsets & tablets, and I support a wide array of screensizes.

Certain devices, like the Motorola XOOM and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, have screen sizes best supported by drawables under configurations like:

```
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi
```

The devices will automatically pick up portrait drawables in those folders when in portrait mode.

However, if I try to create a folder such as:

```
drawable-land-large-mdpi
```

Eclipse will error out with an `Invalid resource directory name` error. Furthermore, despite having a landscape-specific layout that works perfectly on other devices, on these devices when you enter landscape mode it uses the portrait image instead, since (I'm guessing) it can't find an equivalent landscape image.

So what am I supposed to do here to properly support these devices in landscape mode? They look terrible right now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the correct order for the suffixes is:

```
drawable-large-land-mdpi
```

Comment: Correct, the order of the resource qualifiers is depicted in [this table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2).